# Unable to Provide Incrementing Integer ID using Enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, enumerate

I'm working on a script that will scrape a web page using Beautiful Soup. The page contains a number of divs that I want to parse for various pieces of information. For each div, I will create a dictionary. The dictionary contains key-value pairs for the various things I want to pull off the page. I then put each dictionary into a list.

As part of my script, I want to assign an incrementing integer id (0, 1, 2) as a key-value pair in each div. Everything in my script is working except for the code to provide this id. The dummy data that I am working with has 12 divs. The script produces 12 dictionaries, but for each dictionary, the id = 11.

Below is the code that I'm working with. I've commented out the bulk of one of the functions because it didn't seem relevant to this particular problem. I suspect that the problem is somewhere in my "count_headers" function, but I think I'm using enumerate correctly.

```
def extract_metadata(divs):

    header_dict_list = []

    for div in divs:
        header_dict = {}

        header_index = enumerate(divs,0)

        def count_headers(div):
            for num, div in header_index:
                header_id = num
                header_dict['id'] = header_id

        def extract_header_stuff(div):

            # Bunch of stuff happens here to pull out different pieces of information and populate the header_dict for each div. 

        extract_header_stuff(div)

        count_headers(div)

        header_dict_list.append(header_dict)

    print (header_dict_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `enumerate`.  The correct code should be:

```
    for id, div in enumerate(divs) :
        header_dict = {id: id}

        # You probably don't want to define `extract_header_stuff` in the loop
        # either.
```

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for the fast response. I tried your recommended code and now the script does not populate an id key-value pair. `def count_headers(div):
   for id, div in enumerate(divs):
    header_dict = {id: id}`